# Reference songs for interval training (esp. A5/d5; M6; m6)

Tags: theory, intervals, ear-training

As the tutor for my school's music department, I spend a lot of time helping students drill intervals.  However, I only have a handful of songs to recommend recognition.

P8 — Somewhere Over the Rainbow
P5 — Also Sprach Zarathustra
P4 — Here Comes the Bride
m7 — Somewhere (West Side Story)

And there's the extent of my help.  Everything else I work as either arpeggios or scales.  What are good pieces to help my students?  Particularly Tritone and the Major and Minor 6ths.

Comment: never thought of using example songs to memorise intervals. +1 for this interesting question.

Comment: Note to someone: If the context, in which you need to figure out the interval, is a different - such as that the tonic root is different relative to the notes of the interval - than the original for the melody, it can be tricky, but still useful, to use a specific song for interval recognition.

Comment: Just gonna leave this here: [The Interval Song, by Django Bates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl2d4zS56cY).

Answer (score 9):

My music teacher taught us to memorise and recognise intervals using the "compare-it-to-a-familiar-song" method too.

It works really well and *Somewhere Over The Rainbow* was the exact song we used as well.

However, it's only effective if you're actually familiar with the tune - *Also Sprach Zarathustra* doesn't ring any bells with me.

So, as my teacher did, why not play the interval to the student and get **them** to name a tune they know which contains the same interval?

If it happens to be by some obscure X-Factor drop-out, so be it - they'll always remember it because **they** made the link. If you're too proscriptive about the tunes they'll not be able to identify and remember them.

Comment: If you don't know "Also Sprach Zarathustra" do you know the theme from the movie "2001, A Space Oddysey"?

Comment: @MarkLutton Apparently I didn't, as I thought that film used "Fanfare for the Common Man"...

Answer (score 4):

A great one to use for the rising major 6th is the "NBC" motif. Fun fact, NBC was originally a subsidiary of General Electric, and instead of "National Broadcasting Company", "General Electric Company" was used, or G-E-C for short. That initialism spells the notes that make up what is now known as the NBC motif!

Answer (score 4):

M7: Bali Hai, from "South Pacific" -- actually it's an octave jump up followed immediately by a half-step down, but you hear that M7 clearly.

West Side Story is all about tritones. The signal whistle is G C F#.  Jet Song:  G G E C F#.  Maria: C F# G.  Cool:  C F# G C  First sung note of "Gee Officer Krupke" is an F# against C in the bass.

m2:  Jaws theme of course!

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using West Side Story: the canonical mnemonic for the tritone is *Maria*. (In fact, I've never seen anybody use a different one.)

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://fromthewoodshed.com/2011/05/05/songs-for-interval-recognition/) has an extensive list of songs corresponding to the intervals.  It's too much to reproduce here but I will note that it's missing "O Canada" for the ascending minor third :P

Comment: "O Canada" = _minor_ third, right?

Answer (score 1):

m6 - 'Bei Mir Bistu Shein' (or 'Bei Mir Bist Du Schön')
M6 - 'My Bonnie Lies Over the Ocean'

(For most intervals I use(d) non-internationally known songs that I chose myself like Widor so nicely suggests.)

Answer (score 1):

Very nice question.... You brought back memories :)
My music teacher did the exact same thing. I can't seem to recall all the songs she taught us though. I remember she used Singing in the rain for Octave though! :)

Check out this link it has many interesting examples many of which my teacher used as well (like jaws, happy birthday, Superman Theme)

https://web.archive.org/web/20120419063515/http://www.musicalintervalstutor.info/listenpg.html

Widor's answer presents an interesting approach I have to say.

Answer (score 1):

M3 (going down to tonic from major 3rd) = doorbell... ding dong.  Don't laugh - I still use it.  (Love the other examples!)

Answer (score 0):

The stacked thirds from the bridge of *Twist and Shout* by the Beatles. It gives you the whole layout of the scale in one meme.