# Where is the descending tritone in "I Hope I Get It" from "A Chorus Line"?

Tags: intervals

I am looking for reference songs for intervals, and I am told that there is a descending tritone in "I Hope I Get It" from "A Chorus Line". The trouble is, I have no idea where in the song the descending tritone is. Can anyone tell me?

The source of the information is the following website, but it doesn't say where in the song, it just gives the song and musical:

https://www.earmaster.com/products/free-tools/interval-song-chart-generator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to hear it is in the instrumental parts. For example, in the original cast recording (below), it can be heard in the piano at 0:34 (both an ascending and descending tritone) and in the trumpets at 0:49 (again, both ascending and descending).

Written out, with the tritone in red, the part of the music you're looking for goes like this:

[image: "I Hope I Get It" riff]

Also helpful might be this post about interval songs.

- [Reference songs for interval training (esp. A5/d5; M6; m6)](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/7805/70803)